# Converting Ensembl Gene IDs to Entrez Gene IDs through biomart

Tags: gene, public-databases, biomart, conversion

Well, I'm trying to convert a list of Human Gene referenced by Ensembl Gene IDs to Entrez Gene IDs. I [have been advised](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/missing-data-mappings-in-mygene-info-while-trying-to-convert-genes-ensembl-ids-t) to use [biomart](http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martview/).

I tried to get a kind of conversion table for all human genes. I don't know if my settings are wrong, but I didn't find any checkbox for Entrez Gene Id in the section `Attributes` > `External References`. I've just found the Entrez transcript name ID (see below), but it's not what I need.

[image]

How can I use *biomart* for such a conversion?

**Edit:**

<strike>According to [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/DXPaBdPM2vs?t=1m50s) EntrezGene ID should be an option in biomart (see screenshot below).</strike>

That video tutorial is outdated.

Comment: That tutorial is 8 years old.

Comment: Yes, @Emily_Ensembl. I'm sorry, I had gotten it from an old documentation page : )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ID you need is the NCBI gene ID, which is the same as the EntrezGene ID.

Comment: Thank you Ian, it seems working. Anyway, there is no a one-to-one matching (i.e., some Ensembl IDs do not have an NCBI counterpart). Is it normal?

Comment: Yes. See my answer to your other question. https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/2474/235

Answer (score 8):

Conversion using `R`:

```
library(biomaRt)

mart <- useDataset("hsapiens_gene_ensembl", useMart("ensembl"))

    genes <- getBM(
      filters="ensembl_gene_id",
      attributes=c("ensembl_gene_id", "entrezgene_id"),
      values=ensembl.genes,
      mart=mart)
```

Where `ensembl.genes` is a vector of Ensembl gene IDs.

Comment: As of 2021-08-05, the attributes argument should be set to `attributes = c("ensembl_gene_id", "entrezgene_id")`. I believe that the `"_id"` appendage has been added to the attribute since this answer was first posted.